# How to return an array from function react native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, expo

This is my first time working with react expo and I want to return the array to create dynamic components based on this array, but my function is not returning. Below is my code:

```
getgroups = () => {
  // getting data once
  var arraykey = [];
  var returnarry = [];
  returnarry = firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/groupsOfUser/' + this.state.uid)
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        console.log(childKey);
        arraykey.push(childKey);
      }); 
      console.log(arraykey); 
      return arraykey;
    }); 
    console.log('return:' + returnarry[0]);
  } 
}
```

`returnarry` doesn't contain anything. This is the result I am getting when I console log it

**return: undefined**

Please Help!

Comment: Read about sync vs async code

Comment: Also you are not pushing anything in`returnarry`

Comment: I am returning arraykey into returnarry so like I want returnarry=arraykey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it an async function. On the docs, it returns a promise so it must be awaited.

> getgroups = async() => {

And then

```
   returnarry = await firebase
    .database()
```

Answer (score 0):

The JS code execution is asynchronous. The firebase fetching may take some time.

> You can use the async method to handle this. Make your method async as below.

```
getgroups = async() => {
  // getting data once
  var arraykey = [];
  var returnarry = [];
  returnarry = await firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/groupsOfUser/' + this.state.uid)
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        console.log(childKey);
        arraykey.push(childKey);
      }); 
      console.log(arraykey); 
      return arraykey;
    }); 
  }
  console.log('return:' + returnarry[0]);
  return returnarry;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it is correct but Vidor Vinstrom answered the same thing first, that's I marked it correct. I upvoted yours too but have less reputation to publically make my vote count.

Comment: No issues. Thanks for your comment. It is encouraging.